# inserting date into sql script

Tags: sql, sql-server, shell, backup

i am doing sql server backups like this in script:

```
BACKUP DATABASE databasename TO DISK = `path'
```

since this backup is going to be automated, how do i insert today's date into `'path'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @path varchar(255), @mydb varchar(50)
SELECT @mydb = 'MyDBToBackUp'
select @path = 'C:\foo\bar\' + @mydb + '-' + convert(varchar(8),getdate(),112) + '.bak'
BACKUP DATABASE @mydb TO @path
```

[BACKUP DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) takes local variables

Edit: last line should be this: Oops. Sorry.

```
 BACKUP DATABASE @mydb TO DISK =  @path
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get today's date in yyyymmdd format like this

```
convert(varchar(8),getdate(),112)
```

example, change print to exec

```
declare @date varchar(8)
select @date = convert(varchar(8),getdate(),112)

--change print to exec
print ('BACKUP DATABASE databasename TO DISK = ''path' + @date + '''')
```

that will generate this statement

BACKUP DATABASE databasename TO DISK = 'path20100714'

You probably also want to add an extension like BAK

also look into `INIT` and `NOINIT`, `INIT` will overwrite the backup if it already exists with that name `NOINIT` will append, see also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx